# "gs: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libgs.so.9: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set" Error when converting .ai file to .png with ghostscript 9.25

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript

I'm using ImageMagick with ghostscript 9.25 to convert images. When I try to convert .ai file to .png with image magic I'm getting the below error in command line

My command `./convert /home/sample_ai_file2.ai /home/ai_out.png`

```
gs: /opt/software/alfresco-one/common/lib/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /lib64/libgs.so.9)
gs: /opt/software/alfresco-one/common/lib/libjpeg.so.62: no version information available (required by /lib64/libgs.so.9)
gs: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libgs.so.9: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set
.convert.bin: NoImagesForWrite '-write' '/home/sshtest/ai_out.png' at CLI arg 2 @ error/operation.c/CLINoImageOperator/4769.
.convert.bin: NoImageForProperty "%w" @ warning/property.c/GetMagickPropertyLetter/2561.
.convert.bin: UnknownImageProperty "%w" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3499.
.convert.bin: NoImageForProperty "%h" @ warning/property.c/GetMagickPropertyLetter/2449.
.convert.bin: UnknownImageProperty "%h" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3499.
.convert.bin: NoImageForProperty "%m" @ warning/property.c/GetMagickPropertyLetter/2480.
.convert.bin: UnknownImageProperty "%m" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3499.
```

Does any one know the reason for this error ? I can convert all the other image types without any issue.

Comment: At a guess you are using a version of Ghostscript which is built for a different operating system, or for a different configuration. Looks like your build wants to use system shared libraries which are not available (warning; I'm guessing a bit here). Can you run Ghostscript from the command shell ? Note that 9.25 is 3 years old, you might want to look and see if your distro has a newer version.

Comment: @KenS I tried to install the latest version of ghostscript, but I'm getting below message "Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
Package ghostscript-9.25-5.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do "

Comment: Then it sounds like your distro doesn't have a newer version available in a package. Did you try executing Ghostscript from the command shell ? gs --help should display you the usage. This isn't really a Ghostscript question, it's really a question for your OS packager. This sort of problem is one of the reasons we prefer not to use system shared libraries. The other possibility is that your FreeType is out of date, since it's complaining about a FreeType label, you could try and see if there's a newer version of that.

Comment: @KenS thanks for your response, GS commands are working fine in the shell. So I think this should be a issue with my GS version or installation. Currently the centos-7 instance does not have external internet access. This might be the cause for not showing the latest version. I'll try to manually install latest version and try this.

Comment: Hmm well if Ghostscript works in your command shell, then I can't really see why it wouldn't work when run from ImageMagick. Possibly you could check the IM config and see where it is trying to run GS from and make sure it's the same place as your command shell. I'm out of ideas beyond that, I'm not really a Linux expert.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the cause for the above mentioned issue. The error was due to having two versions of GS installed in my system.
When I install ImageMagick, GS 8.64 is also automatically installed by default, then I have again manually installed GS 9.25.
Removing the GS 9.25 resolved my issue.